# MSBuild does not contain a value for the "VCTargetsPath" property

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview to try it out, and now my VS 2010 projects won't open. Instead, I get the following error message:

> MSBuild does not contain a value for the "VCTargetsPath" property

I found someone that had reported the issue [here on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/710360/visual-studio-net-2010-could-not-open-vc-projects-after-installing-visual-studio-net-2011-developer-preview-edition), and the response from Microsoft was:

> Posted by Microsoft on 12/2/2011 at 5:25 PM
>   Hi Afshin,
>
> Thanks for the feedback. The issue you ran into is fixed for the next public release Visual Studio.
>
> Jim Griesmer
>   Visual C++ Team

Fantastic. So how do I restore VCTargetsPath so my projects will work again?

> "VCTargetsPath is a toolset property that is defined in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0. "

I browsed to the VCTargetPath value in the registry and it has the value:

```
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\
```

Not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: These preview editions are less than alpha quality.  Never install anything but RTM on a production machine unless you use a VM.  Repair VS2010, reinstall next.

Comment: This happens with the Customer Preview too, not just those "pre-pre-alphas" you mention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr)

Comment: Broke in latest version of Visual Studio 2017. Apparently it thinks the path is "C:\".  Impossible to build libssh2.

Answer (score 82):

It seems reasonable that the solution Gavin Pugh gave would fix the problem, though I didn't try it.  I too ran into this problem after uninstalling the Developer Preview of VS11.  I think I know what is really wrong though.

Mladen Jankovic was on the right track.  One of the follow two (necessary) registry keys was missing on my machine:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0`

  - Key Name: `VCTargetsPath`
  - Type: `REG_SZ`
  - Value: `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0`

  - Key Name: `VCTargetsPath`
  - Type: `REG_SZ`
  - Value: `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\`

(You can edit registry keys in Windows by typing [image]+R+regedit+Enter)

For me, the second value I listed above was the one that was missing.  After I added it, I was able to work with my project again.

Comment: Worked for me too.  The second key (Wow6432Node) was missing after unstall of VS11 CTP on x64 system.

Comment: There was `VCTargetsPath` in the env variables and found it last when there was nothing to try.

Comment: I had same issue with VS2017. For VS2017 the correct value to set in registry is $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\

Answer (score 7):

Here's the thing that did trick for me:

Change registry value named `DefaultToolsVersion` located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0` from `2.0` to `4.0`. Do the same thing in `Wow6432Node` too.

Answer (score 4):

The registry editing method suggested by "Mladen Jankovic" didn't work for me.

I just ran a repair on Visual Studio 2010 (run the setup.exe on the VS2010 install disc, or invoke the 'uninstall' via Control Panel->Programs). It did the trick for me.

You also should run the SP1 install again.

For what it's worth, my 'add-ins' (including Incredibuild) behaved fine after this. They didn't need to be reinstalled or repaired. My settings/window/debugger placement also was retained.

Apparently this issue only presents itself if you uninstall the Developer Preview of VS11:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/12/15/Do-not-remove-Visual-Studio-2011-developer-preview!.aspx

Answer (score 4):

**For those who are here by google search :**

If you had previously installed VS 2015 or any later versions of vs after vs2010, and then uninstalled, Here is the solution for you.

In the error message below :

> Cannot evaluate the property expression
>   "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\'))"

*14.0 is the version number of VS2015. Unfortunately, the VS2015/2012 uninstaller forgets one of its registry keys, which then causes that error when you go back to VS2010.*

**Go to start/run/ regedit >**

Look for 
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0  (12.0 as well)

And

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0 (12.0 as well )

If there is a key 14.0/12.0 here, **delete** it and your VS2010 will hopefully work again.

Comment: This did indeed fix it for me, but there is one problem: I uninstalled VS2015 because of a problem with the VS2015 installation, but then reinstalled it again, because I need it. So this solution might fix VS2012 but break VS2015.

Comment: For a somewhat better understanding of the problem, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786593/2279059

Answer (score 1):

Ugh I finally found the answer for this, which incidentally didn't give me the same error message - I get:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

For some reason it worked fine with 32-bit builds, but not 64-bit builds.

Anyway, the solution is to copy all the `VCTargetPath*` keys from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild ToolsVersions\14.0` to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0`. They were missing for me.

Actually I only copied `VCTargetsPath` and `VCTargestPath14` because copying is quite tedious. Seems to be sufficient for VC++ 2015.

Answer (score 0):

If working with VS 2010 SP1, go to **Control Panel | Uninstall a program**, Uninstall/Change the **VS 2010 SP1** and pick reapply SP1. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same issue, and found out that the toolset tag was not set in the project node

Setting the tools version solved it for me

Comment: How did you set the tools version?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. @limelights, you can set the tools version in the project properties. In the property pages, look under Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset. You can also do this in your favorite text editor, but you need to know the values.

Answer (score 0):

I used C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe and went to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\3.5 and in the folder for version 3.5 it had 2.0 listed in the  defaulttoolsversion so I modified that to 3.5 and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here when trying to build a c++ project without the c++ Visual Studio build tools installed.  My solution was to download the Visual Studio Build Tools installer from the [downloads page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) under 'Tools for Visual Studio 2017' tab, running the installer with the"Visual C++ build tools" and ".NET Desktop Build Tools" options.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from the missing registry values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0`.

Adding the missing entries with the following commands fixed it.

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0 /v VCTargetsPath /t REG_SZ /d '$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath)'
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0 /v VCTargetsPath14 /t REG_SZ /d '$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath14)'
```