# Visual Studio 2010 Unknown Error on Startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, startup

I'm trying to launch Visual Studio 2010 from my desktop and I just get this error box popping up saying "Unknown Error"...

Anyone have an idea why this might happen?

Comment: I had messed up my "PATH" variable in my computer properties. I correctted my temp path.. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just fixed it, I uninstalled and reinstalled my version of the .NET Framework (v4.0). And then when I again tried to launch Visual studio it started up without any issue.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem after uninstalling Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. This worked for me. I also had another problem afterwards - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497931/msbuild-does-not-contain-a-value-for-the-vctargetspath-property

Answer (score 7):

Here's some things you can check:

- Temporary [de-activate all Addins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228765%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- Temporary [disable all Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293640.aspx)
- Check the [Event Log for any errors](http://www.devtopics.com/how-to-check-the-application-event-log-for-errors/)
- [Reset your settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Start with /ResetSkipPkgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Based on your comment below, if you can't find the DevEnv.exe when you have opened a VIsual Studio Command prompt, I would suggest you to re-install Visual Studio as it indicates your installation (paths) are in a bad state.

And here are some other things you migh want to check:
[VS 2010 Crashes on Startup with "Unknown Error"](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573132/vs-2010-crashes-on-startup-with-unknown-error)
[Visual Studio 2010 quit working...now gives me an "unknown error" dialogue when launched](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560858/visual-studio-2010-quit-working-now-gives-me-an-unknown-error-dialogue-when-launched)
[Visual Studio 2010 Startup Errors](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/148afc2e-1468-4b49-8e96-b471b74d9e90)
[Visual Studio 2010 crashes on startup after installing SP1](http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=172)

Comment: I'm going to sound pretty stupid here.. But how exactly do you do this? This is the first time I'm going to work with C#. I'm literally doing my first 'hello world' tut here...

Comment: I have added links that describes how to do the different steps, hope that helps

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting? Please at least comment on why you feel that my answer should be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Open Visual Studio Command Prompt with Administrator permission and type the following,

```
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
```

Comment: After doing that it says "devenv is not recoginised as a internal or external command, bath file... etc etc etc..."

Comment: are you running Visual Studio command prompt or normal one. If it is normal one, cd <Path to devenv.exe in visual studio installation path>. THen try above command

Comment: run the "Visual Studio command Promt", not the standard windows one. Go `Start=>Programs=>VS2010=>VS tools`

Answer (score 1):

the Solution of this problem ist very simple.

Install VS 2010 on a other machine and export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 to a file. Copy the file to your target machine and rename the path above to ".old", then double click your exported reg-file and wait a time....

After this my Visual Studio was starting correctly.

The other solution, that people post wont work in my case.

I hope this will help some body.

Enjoy

Sven

Comment: VS 2015 had the same registry problems. $ devenv
Cannot find one or more components.  devenv said  Please reinstall the application, devenv /resetuserdata said "Unknown Error.".  Fixed with HLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\  key export, rename to 14.0.broken and import from saved .reg file. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. Instead of completely uninstalling .net framework, I just repaired the .net framework from the repair/uninstall option available in Control Panel of my Windows 7 Ultimate pc.  Finally I got another error that, Visual Studio could not create AppData folder in my system.  Then, I right click the Visual Studio icon and selected Run as Administrator.  This worked for me!! Now, Visual Studio 2010 is working on my pc!! Try this out if you want..