# visual studio 2010 gives unknown error on startup

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am not able to start visual studio. 
I have tried following steps but did not work.

1. Install and uninstall .Net Framework 4.0
2. Install, repair and uninstall  Visual Studio 2010 professional
3. I am not able to even reset settings

While install, repair or unistalling visual studio gives same "Unknown Error" dialog.

I am having Windows 7 Professional (x64) with Intel Xeon Processor.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of or a copy of the exact error text? Have you tried starting it in safe mode ([`/SafeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) switch)? What about with [`/Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) to log all activity?

Comment: I am not able to try even /SafeMode. The exact error text is "Unknown Error" dialog box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 Unknown Error on Startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910406/visual-studio-2010-unknown-error-on-startup)

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect which OS, processor architecture, etc. you have?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional(64 bit), Intel Xeon

Comment: Is the shortcut you're using to launch it targeting `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` or something called `VSLauncher.exe`? If the latter, what happens if you launch it via a `Run` command with the former path?

Comment: Yes, shortcut targets to correct path. Still I am not able to run it fro Run or Command prompt.

Comment: Hmm, well, I've exhausted the options from the little research I did. Most people have solved this error either by reinstalling .NET 4 or doing a "Repair" from the VS 2010 installation media.