# Why does MSBuild look for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props in a unrelated location

Tags: msbuild

I have a Problem which pretty much the bears same anatomy as this post:

[Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr)

Adding the registry (as per the suggestion from Peter Kahn in that other post) did not appear to help, even though it was previously missing. I do have all the files in the correct directory, that is

```
c:\Program Files (X86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110
```

See, if I chose following as MSBuildExtensionsPath

```
MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
```

together with the registry

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\4.0\VCTargetsPath=$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110

HKLM\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\4.0\VCTargetsPath=$(MSBuildExtensionsPath64)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110
```

This should, in theory, end up with the directory where files are stored. But in practice, MSBuild is looking somewhere else:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp.props" could not be found.[..]
```

Even more puzzling: If the $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) is changed to something not in c:\Program Files (X86)\ - for example this:

```
MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = C:\test\MSBuild
```

The resulting error message changes and surprisingly, the path is collated properly:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\test\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" could not be found.[..]
```

Interestingly, this file in fact does exist (copied it there..) and it is still not found.
WTH is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I hate as much as anyone else uninstalling and reinstalling stuff, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16213408/239408 worked for me and did not require any troubleshooting...

Comment: Isn't is stupid to install full Visual Studio when you just need MSBuild tools?

Comment: @Green, maybe it is stupid. And maybe you could post a more informative comment.  In July 2013, having Visual Studio was still the only published approach for my compilation needs https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/commit/088082766caf7562540d0cf1ef7960a7f11995c9#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8

Comment: @xverges that doesn't mean that it's not stupid and a bad design choice by Microsoft