# Node-oracledb fails to run with "Cannot find module '../build/Debug/oracledb'"

Tags: node.js, jasmine, karma-runner, node-oracledb

I'm trying to install the Node oracledb package on Windows 8.1 x64, which is known to be complicated. I followed the instructions in [this detailed article](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127). I still got the error MSB4019 when trying to install, but I solved with [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631063/3307454) in an SO question. But then when running my tests with Karma (jasmine tests), I get this:

> C:\Users\potero\angular\Sunnel_View_Test\unit\jasmine>call karma start
>   C:\Users\
>   potero\angular\Sunnel_View_Test\unit\jasmine\conf\karma.conf.js 04 02
>   2016 11:42:39.758:INFO [framework.browserify]: registering rebuild
>   (autoWa tch=true) 04 02 2016 11:42:40.581:ERROR
>   [framework.browserify]: bundle error 04 02 2016 11:42:40.581:ERROR
>   [framework.browserify]: **Error: Cannot find module
>   '../build/Release/oracledb' from
>   'C:\Users\potero\node_modules\oracledb\lib' 04 02 2016**
>   11:42:40.583:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost
>   :9876/ 04 02 2016 11:42:40.590:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.19 server
>   started at http://lo calhost:9876/ 04 02 2016 11:42:40.599:INFO
>   [launcher]: Starting browser IE 04 02 2016 11:42:40.608:INFO
>   [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome 04 02 2016 11:42:40.613:ERROR
>   [framework.browserify]: bundle error 04 02 2016 11:42:40.613:ERROR
>   [framework.browserify]: Error: Cannot find module
>   '../build/Debug/oracledb' from
>   'C:\Users\potero\node_modules\oracledb\lib' 04 02 2016
>   11:42:40.615:INFO [framework.browserify]: bundle updated 04 02 2016
>   11:42:41.318:INFO [IE 11.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Connected on socke
>   t /#jugOlM6ncxlElbTbAAAA with id 28583632 04 02 2016 11:42:43.555:INFO
>   [Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Connected o n socket
>   /#bwze1YzRw7uyxQfwAAAB with id 57743574
>
> START: IE 11.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR   bundle error (see logs)
>   at
>   C:/Users/potero/AppData/Local/Temp/fcd332ac97c6f0099b6d2cbea5282df8.browser
>   ify:1 Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR   Uncaught Error:
>   bundle error (see logs)   at
>   C:/Users/potero/AppData/Local/Temp/fcd332ac97c6f0099b6d2cbea5282df8.browser
>   ify:1
>
> Finished in 3.922 secs / 0 secs
>
> SUMMARY: V 0 tests completed

There is [a similar issue](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/issues/103) on the package Github page but the solution given there (re installing node) did not work for me. I also re installed oracledb without success.

I checked the folders referred in the error message and the files are not there as stated.

Why does it need those files? Why weren't them installed? Why does it look up for them on my home folder instead that on the folder the project is?

Answer (score 0):

Does PATH have the Oracle client libraries (e.g. Instant Client) in it?