# "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a project created in Visual Studio, 2013.

The project file has the following properties:

ToolsVersion="12.0", 
PlatformToolset = v120.

I have Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Build Tools 2015 installed.
This project gets successfully built using MSBuild 12.0. Upon the attempt to build it with MSBuild 14.0 I get an error

```
MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

As I understand, the problem is that the variable VCTargetsPath doesn’t get evaluated.  If I specify the variable VCTargetsPath before the build (with the value C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120), the problem is solved.

However, this approach is not very convenient in case the path is different. Is it possible to somehow solve the problem in a more optimal way?

The registry key and its value:

```
HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0\VCTargetsPath $([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\'))
```

Comment: *Upon the attempt to build it with MSBuild 14.0* how exactly do you do that? You should probably call vcvars.bat (or equivalent for build tools 2015) first..

Comment: Agree with stijn, please set the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds via vcvars.bat and check if it works for you. For more information about set the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds, please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr)

Answer (score 78):

This will usually solve the problem:

1. Run on an elevated command prompt (admin):
   `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`. Which requires `npm` to be installed (my recommended package manager).
2. Change ownership of the install dir (in my case `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0`) to your user, instead of admin. (properties>Security>Advanced).

Sometimes step 2 is unnecessary. It is still recommended to avoid having to use admin console for some commands.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to (re)run `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools`.

Comment: @Nic Szer can you explain me the second step? I am unable to understand it.

Comment: @NicSzer in my case I am seeing Owner: SYSTEM what should I do?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal you need to change who owns the folder such that your user is the owner, not SYSTEM

Comment: @NicSzer thanks for the reply. I did that but getting new errors now. This is my first time trying to run react native project on windows. I need some help Can we connect on chatroom of stackoverflow?

Comment: Same problem as OP in 2020 and running NPM with these arguments does not work for me. It complains various packages have been deprecated (since February 2020). Although the process completes, the problem still persists.

Comment: How can we install npm if I face the same situation inside a windows container with a base image as `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

Comment: stuck on `Successfully installed Python 2.7`

Comment: @ichimaru more context?

Comment: Why on earth use NPM for this? Isn't NPM a NodeJS package manager?

Comment: @user32882 because of the handy package _windows-build-tools_

Answer (score 71):

I recently reinstalled Visual studio 2017 and encountered this issue while trying to install "npm java".
The fix for me is:

1. set ms version to 2017: `npm config set msvs_version 2017`
2. set VCTargetsPath environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets`
3. run command console as system administrator

Comment: `npm config set msvs_version 2017` this code saved my hours. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex did your `VCTargets` directory already contain `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.Props`? I have the directory but that file is missing.

Comment: @starscream_disco_party yes, Microsoft.Cpp.Default.Props is already in my VCTargets folder

Comment: 2 years later and still running into this issue. Buy a new laptop install everything and then spend days fighting this problem.  the npm config set msvs_version 2017 was the fix for me

Comment: I was having issues to install npm-sass@4.13.0, after running command "npm config set msvs_version 2017" it seems to have solved the problem for me, thanks

Comment: Also works with VS 2022 <3

Answer (score 27):

These steps solved my issue:

1. Run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
2. Run `npm install --save nan`
3. Set `VCTargetsPath` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140`

Comment: where is VCTargetsPath located?

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal `VCTargetsPath` is the name of the environment variable.

Comment: The 3rd step only needed in my case.

Answer (score 27):

For those using VS 2019:

> set VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160"

Edit (Sep 2020):
Sometimes it requires a trailing backslash (as bmiller mentioned below)

Comment: This worked for me.  Note that I also required a trailing backslash on the path, else the build failed looking for specific platform props in a subfolder.

Comment: Worked for me as well, although you need to make sure you specified proper VS version (in my case it was Community - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160"

Comment: Thx, for VS2022, set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170

Comment: Enterprise VS 2019 version can set VCTargetsPath to : 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160

Comment: @LinSongYang Don't forget the backslash at the end; `VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\\`

Answer (score 15):

For those the above answer does not work, here is another possible solution to look at.

Even the installation of build tools or VS 2015 did not work for me. So I tried installing below directly via PowerShell (as admin)

https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualcpp-build-tools/14.0.25420.1 
Command: 
choco install visualcpp-build-tools --version 14.0.25420.1

Once this was installed, set an environment variable VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140

Comment: Using Chocolatey solved it for me, I didn't even set the environment variable, it worked out of the box

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by:

1. Set `VCTargetsPath` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140`
2. build using admin

Answer (score 3):

I could not make it work with all the suggestions on this page

I downgraded nodejs to 10.15 and it worked fine

probably not the best answer but it works

Comment: Yup Node 10 is fine for me, unfortunately our servers are on node 12 now and node 10 is being depreciated so it's off to Linux for me.

Answer (score 3):

When running MSBuild outside of Visual Studio 2019 (migrated from 2012), I had these kinds of problems.
I solved them running this MSBuild:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild"
```

(customize it based on your VS version and target architecture) instead of this one:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild
```

that I was using when I had Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Was running project on Jetbrains Rider without Visual Studio installed (just MSBuild), and got this error.

Fixed it by downloading Visual Studio installer and installing C++ desktop development kit (just the core files - skipped testing, address sanitizer, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by loading the solution in VS 2019 instead of double-clicking the solution name in File Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

After calling VS2019's vcvarsall.bat, it is necessary to use VS2019's MSBuild instead of the one in C:\Windows.

```
set VCVARSALL=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
call "%VCVARSALL%" amd64
set MSBUILD=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
rem set MSBUILD=%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%\msbuild.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

My specific problem was using "yarn install" and during the build process, it was trying to build the node_modules node-sass component using MSBuild, and failing.

I would get the following error: "`error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`"

This makes sense on a new developer machine with only Visual Studio 2022 installed. After investigating the node-sass module's `build\binding.sln` file, it appeared indicate that it requires Visual Studio 2015 VC++ Build Tools.

I then downloaded the "[Visual C++ Build Tools for Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads)" DVD image from Microsoft. After I installed it, it seemed to solve the problem, no PATH or registry changes required. When I ran "yarn install" again, building the module node-sass completed properly.

Answer (score 1):

First I went to the path and confirmed that I didn't have that file. I was able to get that file by

1. opening the Visual Studio Installer,
2. clicking on "Modify" of the current installation
3. selecting "C++ Clang-cl v142 build tools (x64/x86)" under the Individual Components" tab.
4. Confirm the installation by clicking the "Modify" button

Comment: This worked for me. The Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props file was missing from the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160` directory, and this added it there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried npm install and VCTargetsPath, all not work. Finally solved after it after upgrading visual studio to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing **Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows 10**.

Comment: Moving from Express to Pro caused the issue in my case. Set VCTargetsPath environment variable to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me when I used node version 14.15.3, install Node Version Manager, install lower Node version (8.x.x for example), switch to it and that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was that the system environment variable `VisualStudioVersion` was pointing to the removed version of Visual Studio.

The same solution was building ok from inside the Visual Studio but failed when building with the command-line `MSBuild`.

The problem was solved by changing the environment variable manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 2019 and I met the same problem trying to install module 'keytar' on Windows 10. This is what I did in order to solve the problem:

1. Opened "Visual Studio Installer" and removed extra 2017/2019 build tools (for example "Visual Studio Build Tools 2017", restarted the PC
2. Got back into "Visual Studio Installer" / "Visual Studio Professional 2019" / "Modify" and added "Desktop development with C++" workload
3. Got into project folder with my problem, removed node_modules folder
4. Opened CMDO
5. As @TheRennen suggested performed the command:
   set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\
   (without quotation marks and with one backslash at the end)
6. run yarn command and now there were no errors.

I think now it a time to add VCTargetsPath into Windows env values.

node v14.19.0, npm 7.20.5, yarn 1.22.15

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while building my flutter application. The issue arises because of the program in my case flutter was unable to locate the file "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" which is required for building flutter apps in windows.

For solving the issue install MicroSoft Visual Studio(not Visual Studio code) from the below url.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

[Make sure to check the below option before starting installation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSpR1.png)

After installation go to below directory.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC

Note : I have installed community version of 2022 Visual Studio. The folder structure may be different based on your VS version

[You can see few folders with version numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ednpP.png)

Open the folder and check which one have the "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" file . For my case it was the last folder v170. Open Environment variable and set "[VCTargetsPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmFHj.png)" variable with path to the folder in which "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is present. Save path and restart the build process. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2022 it helped to add Build Tools in **Visual Studio Installer**, and my environment variable **VCTargetsPath** was set to:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets`

Note the setting of the system variable **VCTargetsPath** in this **Environment Variables** screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

While checking the .vcxproj file, I noticed the ToolsVersion was missing. I added it and it solves the issue.

Before :

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

After :

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Comment: It seems the relevant content is still missing in the answer. Can you edit it and add that?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to use --global with the command in order to be able to use this package anywhere.
This solves the issue for me