# "C\Microsoft.cpp.default.props" was not found when building Beckhoff Twincat 3 program

Tags: node.js, vb.net, npm, twincat

I'm trying to build a basic program using Beckhoff Twincat 3 which uses Visual Studio. This is the error I am getting when I try to build:

MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Things I've tried:

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools.npm` ([from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695251/c-microsoft-cpp-default-props-was-not-found)) in an admin command prompt which gives me:

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install --global --production windows-build-tools.npm
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools.npm - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'windows-build-tools.npm@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\15198\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-04T18_37_32_858Z-debug-0.log
```

I've also set my VCTargetsPath environment Variable to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170` as well as input a registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0`.

I'm a student trying to get this to work for a school project so it's possible I maybe routed to an incorrect directory or something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't copy the command correctly, omit ".npm" from that npm command argument.