# Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props error while compiling C++ code using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have upgraded C++ project from Visual Studio 2010 (PlatformToolset v100) to Visual Studio 2019 (PlatformToolset v142). I have installed VS 2019 community edition. While compiling the code using developer command prompt with mvn install command getting below error:

*.vcxproj: error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

while compiling using **msbuild test.sln** command, code gets compiled successfully.

I also tried using Visual Studio build tools but was getting same error.

After setting **VCTargetsPath** to **$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0** still getting the same error but the path got changed.

**Error:** *.vcxproj: error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

I verified the path C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0 which contains v140 directory.

Please let me know if anyone have any idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695251/c-microsoft-cpp-default-props-was-not-found

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I already tried it but no luck.

Comment: Have you installed C++ workload in Visual Studio Installer? How about setting  VCTargetsPath   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160`