# How to install "Visual C++ Build Tools" for Visual Studio Professional 2017

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

When installing Visual Studio Professional 2017 it's easy to find and install the MSBuild component, but it only supports C#/VB. I need to be able to use MSBuild to build C++ projects as I've done in the past. According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/?__hstc=268264337.5b0c3ee03939a72343398e64f811c0b7.1493337652644.1493337652644.1493337652644.1&__hssc=268264337.1.1493337652645&__hsfp=3296697578) blog there is supposed to be a "Visual C++ Build Tools" workload, but I can't find this (I've stared at the installer for ages). Do I need to install a different edition or did something change between the 2017 RC and the actual release?

**EDIT 1**: If there is no way to install "Visual C++ Build Tools" how do I get MSBuild C++ support? Installing the "Desktop development with C++" workload does not include it, as far as I can tell, and there does not appear to be any individual components that provide it either.  Is there a separate installer I can download?

**EDIT 2**: I tried using the command line installer as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools), like so:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer>vs_installer.exe modify --installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional" --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```

This results in the installer GUI being displayed with no additional workloads or components selected (so, it's not possible to continue installing anything).  I give up for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.0) (x86 and x64) - (Multiple Languages)" installer under my MSDN subscription when I searched for "2017".  This seems to be what I was looking for.

However, in the past I relied on setting `VCTargetsPath` for my MSBuild scripts as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222039/1718477) SO thread (after testing it looks like I still need it in VS2017). When I searched for "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props", I found that it was located under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets
```

but also under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets
```

So, it appears that this was installed by the regular VS2017 installer for one of the workloads I installed, but also when I installed the build tools installer separately.  I don't have time to figure out the exact details at the moment, but hopefully this will save someone some time.