# Microsoft.cpp.default.props not found when running npm install

Tags: npm, msbuild, node-gyp, node-fibers

There are many issues related to this subject however I have tried all of the following solutions to no avail:

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools /*and*/ npm config set msvs_version 2015
```

install Visual Studio Build Tools (both 8.1 and 10 sdks)
 
set VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\(v110, v120, v140)"

and pretty much any other internet solution. My error is:

```
PS C:\Users\hawki\idle-api> npm install

> fibers@1.0.15 install C:\Users\hawki\idle-api\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js


C:\Users\hawki\idle-api\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\hawki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Users\hawki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\hawki\idle-api\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxpr
oj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft
.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the
 <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\hawki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\hawki\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\hawki\idle-api\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN rollback Rolling back ajv@4.11.8 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\hawki\idle-api\node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'npm WARN idleapi@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN idleapi@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hawki\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-16T18_05_11_310Z-debug.log
```

I am running this in Visual Studio Code, and I think the issue started after I downloaded Visual Studio 2017. I assume it should be solved in my regedit, but I have tried the solutions found here [Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr/16213408#16213408) and nothing seems to work, or even change the original error. If anyone could walk me through the steps to fixing this that would be much appreciated

Comment: where `Microsoft.Cpp.Defaults.props` is exists on your location? Could you confirm the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft
.Cpp\v4.0\V110` is correct? If not, please set the environment variable VCTargetsPath to the directory location where Microsoft.Cpp.Defaults.props is installed