# CMake could not find any instance of Visual Studio, openvino

Tags: cmake, intel, avx, avx2, openvino

Because of avx instruction not available in my cpu, i used copy the **cpu_extensionavx2.dll**

removing avx2 and copy in the build folder

I had already run setupvars.bat using the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\setupvars.bat"
```

It is working.

While running `cmake` by running this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" ^
  -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" ^
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\inference_engine\samples"
```

it throws the following error, even when I changed to **visual studio 16** but gave same error:

```
(base) C:\Users\ra\build>
(base) C:\Users\ra\build> "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" ^
More?   -G "Visual Studio 16" ^
More?    "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\inferenc
e_engine\samples"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/ra/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

but when I used this command:

```
 "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" ^
 -G "Visual Studio 20" ^
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\inferene_engine\samples"
```

it throws **generator error** as:

e_engine\samples"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  Generator

```
Visual Studio 15 2017
```

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/ra/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

```
(base) C:\Users\ra\build> "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" ^
More?   -G "Visual Studio 20" ^
More?    "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\inferenc
e_engine\samples"

CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 20
Generators
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
* NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

I am running Windows 7 64-bit, all are installed CMake latest version.
Help me.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, do you have an instance of Visual Studio [installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) on your machine? Also, when calling CMake, you must use a properly-formatted generator name, such as `"Visual Studio 16 2019"` or `"Visual Studio 14 2015"`. These are also listed in the error message.

Comment: I had installed visual studio many times, also written all generator names as possible  all giving error ;(

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed? Did you try running the `cmake` command from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt? You can access it from the Windows Start Menu.

Comment: just i again downloaded it today,  this error i was solving was of that openvino unsupported avx, i done all i am stuck in this [error](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14409#issuecomment-486605244)

Comment: yeah cmake didnt run in visual studio command prompt

Comment: oh it ran but showing  this
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>cmake
Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
  cmake [options] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'cmake --help' for more information.


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>

Comment: In my earlier comment, I meant to ask if you ran the full `cmake` command: `"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" ^
  -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" ^
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\inference_engine\samples"` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, as stated in the [instructions](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14409#issuecomment-486605244).

Comment: :(  i ran shows another error saying cmake error at cmakelists.txt , failed to run msbuild command: msbuild.exe    ... to get the value of VCTargetsPath ..... exit code 1 , configuring incomplete

Comment: i seen cmakoutput log shows

The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64

Comment: To be clear, before running the full `cmake` command, did you also run the `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\setupvars.bat"` command in the **same** Visual Studio Command Prompt? It is important that these [steps](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14409#issuecomment-486605244) must be completed *in order* and all from within the **same** Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: gone in  build directory of my username, and run setupvars as mention, ran second got another error saying      C:\Users\ra\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB
4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\
Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Comment: please help me it didnt worked

Comment: This appears to be a different error than what was written in your original question post. There are several solutions for this kind of error: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270957/3987854).

Comment: :( , i tried didnt solved the problem, i am asking question,
Thankyou very much friend :) helping me, after 3 days , i think i am now on solution of my problem

Comment: problem not solved help me

Comment: yaaaay thankyou @squareskittles you are great i have successfully build and got the cpu_extensions.dll , now got another openvino specific problems,

Answer (score 0):

You can build the demos automatically using the bat script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\inference_engine\demos\build_demos_msvc.bat"
```

You can also build them manually if you wish.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\bin\setupvars.bat"
md build
cd build
cmake -A x64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021\inference_engine\demos
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Please ensure your system meets the [system requirements](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/system-requirements.html) and you are using a supported OS. For Windows, only Windows 10 is supported.

**Processors**

- 6th to 11th generation Intel® Core™ processors
- List item 1st to 3rd generation
  of Intel® Xeon® Scalable processors