# MSBUuild is looking for "...\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" when we have ".../\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

While building the project "Common.vcxproj", We are getting Error message : error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The machine has the tool installed at  "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" , but the .vcxproj is looking for "V110" folder.
In the Project file ""
and We have registry key = "VCTargetsPath"  and value = $([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\'))

Question is why the MSBUuild is looking for "...\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" when we have ".../\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"?

Thanks

Comment: I've seen this happen on computers with only 1 version of VS and Windows SDK installed. If the PlatformToolset and/or WindowsTargetPlatformVersion properties are not or incorrectly set in the project file, the core msbuild files fail to derive the currently installed version and instead default to V110 resulting in this kind of fairly useless error messages.

Answer (score 0):

> Question is why the MSBUuild is looking for
> "...\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" when we have
> ".../\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"?

Please try these:

**1)** please check register editor and enter both `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0` and then make sure that it uses v140's path as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr/44245728#44245728) shows.

**2)** Right-click on your project in VS 2015 IDE-->`Properties`-->`Configuration Properties`-->`General`-->change `Platform Toolset` to `v140`.

**3)** Also, check whether you define any `VCTargetPath` under Project Properties(right-click on your project)-->xxxxx-->Command Line

**4)** Run `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools` in Powershell as administrator

**5)** If these does not work, please go back to step one, and then change `VCTargetsPath` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\` directly.

Or run `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("VCTargetsPath", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140", "Machine")` in powershell.

Hope these could help you.