# Cannot get Visual 2010 to make new projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to work in Visual Studio 2010 and whenever I try to start a new project or open an existing one, I get an error depending on the situation. I have .NET 4.0 installed, but it seems like VS2010 is trying to use .NET 2.0, as it comes up with this error:

[image: Error One]

After using Google, I delete the Registry entry for that and use .NET cleanup to remove all .NET versions. I reinstalled .NET 4.0 and tried again. Now, I get this:

[image: Error Two]

I thought I found a registry fix, but it didn't work

Comment: A similar question is here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497931/msbuild-does-not-contain-a-value-for-the-vctargetspath-property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497931/msbuild-does-not-contain-a-value-for-the-vctargetspath-property) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Better take a look at the [feedback given in Microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729405/after-installing-2011-vs2010-reports-msbuild-does-not-contain-a-value-for-the-vctargetspath-property).

Maybe you may need to work around with your `SP1` or make use of the workaround suggested the Microsoft Connect [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497931/msbuild-does-not-contain-a-value-for-the-vctargetspath-property/9304298#9304298).

Comment: @John Would like to know which answer helped you in that question?