# Upgrading VC++ project from VS 2008 to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, msbuild

I am trying to upgrade my projects' target framework version from 2.0 to 4.0, for that  I have opened my project's solution into VS 2012.
The other VB and C# projects are successfully upgraded, during upgrading VC++ project I got this message in "UpgradeLog.xml" file "MSBuild does not contain a value for the "VCTargetsPath" property"

Due to above error the VC++ project upgrade is failed, I don't know what that error means. Is this related with VC++ Redistributable?

Am I missing something here during upgrade process?

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSBuild does not contain a value for the "VCTargetsPath" property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497931/msbuild-does-not-contain-a-value-for-the-vctargetspath-property)

Comment: @demonplus the solutions provided over there are not worked in my case, and I do not have installed/Uninstalled VS 11.

Comment: *project upgrade is failed* Do you mean the project cannot be opened in VS? Or does it not build?

Comment: @stijn - I the mean project cannot be opened in VS 2012, the solution explorer saying "ProjecName(unavailable)".